# Aws s3 not taking MultipartFile and not working normal File upload to tomcat server after deploy and working on locally

Tags: java, file, amazon-s3, multipart

On uploading file to aws s3 bucket, its working fine locally. But when i deployed project on tomcat server its giving error to write `fileoutputstream` **(permission denied)**

Here is the image

[image]

Here is my code

```
private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
    }

    private String generateFileName(MultipartFile multiPart) {
        return new Date().getTime() + "-" + multiPart.getOriginalFilename().replace(" ", "_");
    }

    private void uploadFileTos3bucket(String fileName, File file) {
        s3client.putObject(
                new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    }
```

and when i change to File to `Multipartfile` its show's me this error

[image]

Also if i am uploading multipart directly to s3 bucket, its giving error to cast it into file. And if i am casting file to multipart than its giving (I/O) Exception

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in this method:

There is no issue regarding S3, you getting this issue because you are using **fileOutputstream**, you not specified any folder to write a file.But by default it writes a file to **target** folder in your project.

```
private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
}
```

So i solved the code by creating a **folder** to **tomcat** **server**, while uploading.
When the request comes next time. I delete the existing directory and create it again just for writing files.

Use the code below:

```
private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
                deleteDir(new File(NsdlUrlListService.einvoicePath)); //delete a dir

                File files = new File("home/ubuntu/txtgenie/einvoice/"); //create a dir
                if (!files.exists()) {
                    if (files.mkdirs()) {
                        logger.debug("Multiple directories are created!");
                    } else {
                        logger.debug("Failed to create multiple directories!");
                    }
                }

            File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
            FileOutputStream fos = new 
                            FileOutputStream("/home/ubuntu/txtgenie/einvoice/"+convFile);

            logger.info(" File Name:: {} ", file);
            String fileName = null;

                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();

                if (!fileName.equals("No file")) {
                    try {
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                                new FileOutputStream(new File("home/ubuntu/txtgenie/einvoice/" 
                                                      + fileName)));
                        bos.write(bytes);
                        bos.close();
                    }
                      catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                            logger.debug("File not found" + fnfe);
                        }
                        catch (IOException ioe) {
                            logger.debug("Error while writing to file" + ioe);
                        }
                }
            fos.write(file.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            return convFile;
        }
```

TO delete dir

```
private boolean deleteDir(File file) {
    logger.debug("DIR to delete :: " +file);
     if (file.isDirectory()) {
         String[] children = file.list();
         for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir (new File(file, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
               return false;
            }
         }
      }
      logger.debug("The directory : "+file+" : is deleted.");
      return file.delete();
}
```